# Opencart display one module conents into another module

Tags: module, merge, opencart

I'm having **custom footer module** in my template. Also i'm using **testimonial module** in the position **content bottom**. I'm trying to display testimonial inside custom footer.

To do this i simply copied testimonial.tpl and testimonial.php contents and pasted into customfooter.tpl and customfooter.php

After this i'm getting errors stating

```
undefined variable and class name already assigned error
```

Did you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer for how to do use a module in a separate modification/controller

[opencart - How to manually display a module inside a template file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819839/opencart-how-to-manually-display-a-module-inside-a-template-file/8841843#8841843)

You simply need to change from the common/home to your module's controller and view files

Answer (score 0):

please define variable.

how can you define i will show you.

catalog > controller > header.php

for static variable

```
$this->load->language('common/header');
$data['text_home'] = $this->language->get('text_home');
```

// Where language file in assign this variable with different language foler

```
$data['text_home'] = $this->url->link('information/contact');
```

and you can tpl file in use this varible.

```
<?php echo $text_home; ?>
```

make sure 100% erorr has not facing

for dynamic variable