# Opencart Adding module inside another module

Tags: module, custom-controls, opencart

I'm having two modules.

1. custom footer.
2. Testimonial.

Now I'm trying to display testimonial module inside custom footer. Like another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819839/opencart-how-to-manually-display-a-module-inside-a-template-file/8841843#8841843) I have added

```
// Display testimonial part
        $this->data['testimonial_block'] = $module = $this->getChild('module/testimonial', array(
        'limit' => 5,
        'image_width' => 80,
        'image_height' => 80
        ));
```

in `"catalog/controller/common/customfooter.php"` before `$this->render ();`

And added `<?php echo $testimonial_block; ?>` inside `customfooter.tpl`

After adding this i'm getting this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: testimonial_title in C:\xampp\htdocs\magichomegym\catalog\controller\module\testimonial.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: testimonial_limit in C:\xampp\htdocs\magichomegym\catalog\controller\module\testimonial.php on line 22
```

Did anyone knows where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply the relevant data in the array

```
$this->data['testimonial_block'] = $module = $this->getChild('module/testimonial', array(
    'limit' => 5,
    'image_width' => 80,
    'image_height' => 80,
    'testimonial_title' => 'Title here',
    'testimonial_limit' => 5,
));
```

Replacing the 5 with the amount of testimonials you want to display and the 'Title here' with whatever you want the title to be