# How to insert module in header tpl file in opencart 2.0?

Tags: opencart2.x

How to insert a module in `header.tpl` file in opencart 2.0 ?

I have a module. Does not have the layout position option for that module.
So i need to place that manually in `header.tpl` file.

I am already [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819839/opencart-how-to-manually-display-a-module-inside-a-template-file) but not working for opencart 2.0.

Please any one help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In opencart 2.0 or above you can load the contoller of module :-

```
$data['anyname'] = $this->load->controller('modulefolder/filename');
```

And In that module's controller file there should be a return of what it render.Like:

```
return $this->load->view('default/template/modulefolder/filename.tpl', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong

```
$['special_block'] = $module = $this->getChild('module/special', array(
    'limit' => 5,
    'image_width' => 80,
    'image_height' => 80
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.This also not working bro.I need to render a module in header.tpl file.If u know please reply me .

Answer (score 1):

For example you have a custom module named "testmodule" under common folder

if you want to insert this module in header you need to do following thing

1. Load controller on catalog/controller/common/header.php

   ```
    $data['testmodule'] = $this->load->controller('common/testmodule');
   ```
2. Echo the following code on header template file i.e. view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl

   ```
    <?php echo $testmodule; ?>
   ```

This will work