# Stores array in opencart 2.0 header won't load

Tags: header-files, opencart2.x

I tried to add stores into the header of `opencart 2.0`

In the controller of the header:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Analytics
        $this->load->model('extension/extension');

        $data['analytics'] = array();

        $analytics = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('analytics');

        foreach ($analytics as $analytic) {
            if ($this->config->get($analytic['code'] . '_status')) {
                $data['analytics'][] = $this->load->controller('analytics/' . $analytic['code']);
            }
        }

        if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
            $server = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
        } else {
            $server = $this->config->get('config_url');
        }

        if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_icon'))) {
            $this->document->addLink($server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_icon'), 'icon');
        }

        $data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle();

        $data['base'] = $server;
        $data['description'] = $this->document->getDescription();
        $data['keywords'] = $this->document->getKeywords();
        $data['links'] = $this->document->getLinks();
        $data['styles'] = $this->document->getStyles();
        $data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts();
        $data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code');
        $data['direction'] = $this->language->get('direction');
        $data['name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');

        if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_logo'))) {
            $data['logo'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
        } else {
            $data['logo'] = '';
        }

        $this->load->language('common/header');

        $data['text_home'] = $this->language->get('text_home');

// stores //
            $this->load->language('module/store');

            $data['store_id'] = $this->config->get('config_store_id');

            $data['stores'] = array();

            $data['stores'][] = array(
                'store_id' => 0,
                'name'     => $this->language->get('text_default'),
                'url'      => HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=common/home&session_id=' . $this->session->getId()
            );

            $this->load->model('setting/store');

            $results = $this->model_setting_store->getStores();

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $data['stores'][] = array(
                    'store_id' => $result['store_id'],
                    'name'     => $result['name'],
                    'url'      => $result['url'] . 'index.php?route=common/home&session_id=' . $this->session->getId()
                );
            }

// stores //        


        // Wishlist
        if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
            $this->load->model('account/wishlist');

            $data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), $this->model_account_wishlist->getTotalWishlist());
        } else {
            $data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) ? count($this->session->data['wishlist']) : 0));
        }

        $data['text_shopping_cart'] = $this->language->get('text_shopping_cart');
        $data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL'));
        $data['text_account'] = $this->language->get('text_account');
        $data['text_klantenservice'] = $this->language->get('text_klantenservice');

        $data['text_register'] = $this->language->get('text_register');
        $data['text_login'] = $this->language->get('text_login');
        $data['text_order'] = $this->language->get('text_order');
        $data['text_transaction'] = $this->language->get('text_transaction');
        $data['text_download'] = $this->language->get('text_download');
        $data['text_logout'] = $this->language->get('text_logout');
        $data['text_checkout'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout');
        $data['text_category'] = $this->language->get('text_category');
        $data['text_all'] = $this->language->get('text_all');

        $data['home'] = $this->url->link('common/home'); 
        $data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', 'SSL');
        $data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
        $data['account'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL');
        $data['register'] = $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL');
        $data['login'] = $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL');
        $data['order'] = $this->url->link('account/order', '', 'SSL');
        $data['transaction'] = $this->url->link('account/transaction', '', 'SSL');
        $data['download'] = $this->url->link('account/download', '', 'SSL');
        $data['logout'] = $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL');
        $data['shopping_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
        $data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');
        $data['contact'] = $this->url->link('information/contact');
        $data['telephone'] = $this->config->get('config_telephone');


        $status = true;

        if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            $robots = explode("\n", str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", trim($this->config->get('config_robots'))));

            foreach ($robots as $robot) {
                if ($robot && strpos($this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], trim($robot)) !== false) {
                    $status = false;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Menu
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category['top']) {
                // Level 2
                $children_data = array();

                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

                foreach ($children as $child) {

                     if ($child['image']) {
                        $image = $child['image'];
                    } else {
                        $image = 'placeholder.png';
                    }

                    $filter_data = array(
                        'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true
                    );

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']),
                        'thumb' => $child['image'],

                    );
                }

                // Level 1
                $data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name'     => $category['name'],
                    'children' => $children_data,
                    'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id']),
                    'thumb'     =>  $category['image'],
                );
            }
        }

        $data['language'] = $this->load->controller('common/language');
        $data['currency'] = $this->load->controller('common/currency');
        $data['search'] = $this->load->controller('common/search');
        $data['cart'] = $this->load->controller('common/cart');

        // For page specific css
        if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
            if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
                $class = '-' . $this->request->get['product_id'];
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                $class = '-' . $this->request->get['path'];
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
                $class = '-' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];
            } else {
                $class = '';
            }

            $data['class'] = str_replace('/', '-', $this->request->get['route']) . $class;
        } else {
            $data['class'] = 'common-home';
        }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl')) {
            return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl', $data);
        } else {
            return $this->load->view('default/template/common/header.tpl', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

in the `header.tpl`:

```
<!-- stores -->         

<div class="fadelink fadelink_links">   
            <a><?php echo $name; ?></a> 

<div class="ul_wrapper">
<ul>
  <?php foreach ($stores as $store) { 
  if ($store['store_id'] == $store_id) { ?>
  <li> <a href="<?php echo $store['url']; ?>"><b><?php echo $store['name']; ?></b></a> </li>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <li> <a href="<?php echo $store['url']; ?>"><?php echo $store['name']; ?></a> </li>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>      

<!-- stores -->
```

In the controller something goes wrong since the aray stores won't load data. I tested it with another module and with $stores = 'value'; and those both work fine. Only difference is that the stores value is a config value. Someone has a clue what i'm not seeing?

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358240/how-to-insert-module-in-header-tpl-file-in-opencart-2-0#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358240/how-to-insert-module-in-header-tpl-file-in-opencart-2-0#_=_)

Comment: Show full code of `header.php` controller file

Comment: Is this code is for front-end? Or for admin?

Comment: updated the controller code

Comment: There is nothing like `$data['stores']` in controller file

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your tpl file.
It should be

```
<?php foreach ($stores as $store) { ?>
  <?php if ($store['store_id'] == $store_id) { ?>
   <li> <a href="<?php echo $store['url']; ?>"><b><?php echo $store['name']; ?></b></a> </li>
  <?php } else { ?>
   <li> <a href="<?php echo $store['url']; ?>"><?php echo $store['name']; ?></a> </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It also has the same problem with language in the header ---- CONTROLLER ---$data['text_you_are'] = $this->language->get('text_you_are');--- languange ---$_['text_you_are]           = 'You Are at';--- TEMPLATE --- <a><?php echo $text_you_are .' '. $name; ?></a>  ----- This should work fine normaly but also UNDEFINED VAR

Comment: The language error is arising because you are using `$this->load->language('module/store');` where as you should use `$this->load->language('setting/store');`. The model and language path are usually the same. I mean both are in respective folders.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the variable in your tpl file, you **NEVER** use `$data`. Instead you use `$variable` name. In the tpl file, Just change `$data['stores']` to `$stores`.

CHANGE

```
<?php foreach ($data['stores'] as $store) { ?>
```

TO

```
<?php foreach ($stores as $store) { ?>
```

Comment: thanks. Noted. Still it is an error in the controller file since there is no data transfered to the tpl

Comment: Where did you initialized `$data['stores']` in the controller?